# Can't start tomcat in digital Oceans's CentOS server

Tags: tomcat, server, centos, war, digital-ocean

I am trying to configure CentOS system in DigitalOcean server. Earlier I configured Ubuntu server and faced no problem. I followed all those steps provided in their website. But this time I can't configure server perfectly. I can't start tomcat in CentOS server. I am following steps of this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7)  . I am doing everything as they said. But every time I am getting this output when I check tomcat status

```
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since সোম 2019-01-21 10:31:05 UTC; 7s ago
  Process: 26985 ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 26972 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 26983 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

জানু 21 10:31:05 IRDMinistry systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered....
জানু 21 10:31:05 IRDMinistry systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Is their any problem in those steps or Something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options.
1) Check if you haven't set Heap memory bigger than your VMs RAM. Set it 40% or RAM. You can do in /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service @ this line.

> Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server
>   -XX:+UseParallelGC'

2) Also, an easy way how to check is either in Catalina logs. By tutorial, they should be here and mostly named catalina.out

> /opt/tomcat/logs

Or switch to tomcat user ( command: su - tomcat ) and execute tomcat manually /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh .. This should print out the error if something is wrong